# Determine if $f_n(x) = n^2x(1-x^2)^n$ converges uniformly on $E=[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine if $f_n(x) = n^2x(1-x^2)^n$ converges uniformly on $E=[0,1]$. We can easily find the pointwise limit to be $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in E$. $M_n = \sup\limits_{x\in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = \sup\limits_{x\in E} |f_n(x)| = \sup\limits_{x\in E} f_n(x)$ since $f_n$ is always positive on $E$. I am having trouble finding the supremum of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f_n(\frac{1}{n}) = n(1-\frac{1}{n^2})^n \geq n(1-\frac{1}{n})^n$, which asymptotically looks like $\frac{n}{e}$, and thus tends to $\infty$.

Therefore there exists a sequence $x_n \to 0$ such that $f_n(x_n) \to \infty$, so the convergence is not uniform (here $x_n = \frac{1}{n})$.

Comment: Elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Well, do it Calculus I style: $$f_n'(x) = n^2((1-x^2)^n - 2nx^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}).$$ We have $$f_n'(x) = 0 \iff (1-x^2)^{n-1}(1-x^2-2nx^2) = 0$$ So our critical points are $x = 0$, $1$ and the solutions to $$1-x^2-2nx^2 = 0,$$ that is: $$1-x^2(1+2n)=0 \implies x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}},$$ since $0 \leq x \leq 1$. It is easy to check that this is indeed a maximum. So $$\|f_n\|_{\infty} = \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{1+2n}}\left(1-\frac{1}{1+2n}\right)^n = \frac{2^nn^{n+2}}{(1+2n)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}} \to +\infty,$$ but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2n}}\to 0$, so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: The maximum occurs at $x^*=1/\sqrt{1+2n},$    but $f_n(x^*)$ is in fact unbounded!   Check my work, but I believe $f(x^*) = \frac{n^2 (-1 + \sqrt{1+2n})^n}{(1+2n)^{0.25 + 0.5n} }$

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'_n(x)=n^2(1-x^2)^n-2n^3x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}=n^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}\left(1-(1+2n)x^2\right)$$

The supremum of $f_n$ Is reached at $x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+2n}}$. So

$$M_n=n^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\left(\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)^n$$

$M_n\to \infty$ and therefore the convergence is not uniform